# How to access RabbitMq publicly

Tags: centos, rabbitmq

I have installed & setup the Rabbitmq on Centos remote server. Later I created an file "rabbitmq.config" and added the line

> [{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}]

and then restarted the rabbitmq server. Again tried to login the rabbitmq management web interface from my local machine using the guest credentials, but getting

> login failed

error message.What is the proper way to empty the loopback user settings for Rabbitmq in Centos.

Comment: I answered your question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020908/how-to-access-rabbitmq-publicly/23029585#23029585.